# Question about conditional probability of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with the following: X and Y are two independent continuous random variables with marginal probability density functions f<sub>X</sub> and f<sub>Y</sub> respectively. Show that P(X ≤ Y|Y = y) = P(X ≤ y). I recognize that P(X ≤ Y) is the continuous density function F<sub>X</sub>(Y), and I'm thinking that the first probability can be written as an integral (or multiple integrals) of the probability density functions, but I'm not sure I completely understand how to go about this. Any help with this proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem mistakenly to be calling the *cumulative distribution function* $F_X,$ or CDF, the "continuous density function."

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's continuous or not, we have $$P(X\leq Y|Y=y)=P(X\leq y|Y=y)$$ and due to independence, we should have $P(X\leq y|Y=y)=P(X\leq y)$.